# How to create a view thats filter a group or person type field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter, view, library

I have a Person or Group field called Teachers that I created in Infopath. It can contain only one user for the current project and it's not a SharePoint Group.

How I can create a view to filter the project based on the current login user? This would allow Users to only see forms which have their name in a column. I try to use [Me] parameter but getting the following error:

[image]

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `person/group field is equal to [Me]`, not contains. Even if the person/group field contains multiple users, it will still filter correctly when using is equal to [Me].

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for the quick prompt answer but can you elaborate more? In the view When i tried to filter my Teachers column by the parameter  [Me]  i have the error mentionned in the post. Maybe i did something wrong but can you elaborate more?

Comment: @djgibbs are you setting the operator to "equal to" or "contains"? As the error reads, it looks like you are using the "contains" operator on a lookup column.

Comment: @djgibbs the error you are receiving is because you are using contains as the operator, you must use is equal to.

Comment: @EricAlexander do you mean, even if the users column has 2-3 users, when we use "Field Equals [Me]" it'll work for all 3 users?